# Is it possible to shift a video track a fraction of a second in Sony Vegas Pro 10?

Tags: vegas-pro

I've got 2 video sources and they don't line up perfectly to the second.  One is a fraction of a second behind the other.  When I click-and-drag one of the video tracks, it automatically snaps to the nearest full second mark.  I've tried unchecking the "Snap To Grid" option but it still snaps to the full second.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>dragging</kbd> ignores grid, markers, fade-in/fade-out marks, and all other time points that otherwise would cause "sticking".

The same applies to dragging the *Event* entirely and its start/stop borders.